# How does this useEffect firebase clean-up function works?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I watched a tutorial about realtime chatroom of using react and firebase. The below code is the AuthContext file and can someone explain the part of useEffect, why the clean-up function is simply unsub()?

[The tutorial link](https://youtu.be/k4mjF4sPITE?si=mXXVEfEnr3W91fsM&t=4283)

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      console.log(user);
    });

    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I tried finding the solution online but not really related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the clean-up function is simply `unsub()`

It is because the [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onauthstatechanged) method from the Firebase JS SDK returns a function that unsusbcribes from the Observer.

So doing `const whateverVariableName = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {...})` sets the Observer and assigns the function to the variable. Then doing `whateverVariableName()` (note the brackets) unsubscribes from the Observer.